# I'm stuck at pushing Docker images to GitHub Container Repository

Tags: docker, github, ghcr, github-container-registry

I'm trying to push a Docker image to `ghcr.io`. But I'm stuck.

I have created an action on GitHub, that logs into `ghcr.io` using this code:

```
echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
```

And it passes as a successful step in my GitHub action. I see this response:

> Login Succeeded

Then I try to push using this command:

```
docker push ghcr.io/organization_name/repository_name:latest
```

And my organization is private. It shows me this error:

> denied: installation not allowed to Create organization package
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I go to `ghcr.io` to manually create the repository (just the way we do on Docker Hub), but it's navigation does not have a good UX, at least in my opinion. I click **Get Started** on their home page, and it takes me to docs page. And when I click **Quick Start** there, it shows a sample of publishing NPM package. There I see that you should go to your repositories **container landing page** but I see no link to click to navigate there or no menu item anywhere.

Also I can't find out how to create this package repository using [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry)

How should I proceed?

Comment: @Dolphin, delete the packages from the Organization page. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not granted the right permission to the token. You need to give it the `write:package` permission (can be changed when you open the details of your personal access token).

Comment: The problem was not the permission. It was because I had deleted this repo and recreated it with the exact name. I had to go and manually delete the package that had been upload previously, directly from the organization packages page. Then it worked.

Comment: the github token was generate automatically, how to change the permission?

Comment: Go to your Settings » Developer Settings » Personal Access Tokens. You see a list of all tokens and when you *edit* them, you can alter the permissions. The UI differs a bit, depending on whether you use the new fine-grained tokens or the classic tokens.